# Am I swapping elements from a list correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, swap

Info: I am a HS student who is learning how to code and I don't know of anyone who can check my logic for me, so I am using the kind souls of Stack Overflow to help check my thinking.

Actual question: I am learning about sorting, and I want to know if I actually understand what is going on during the swapping proccess.

```
my_list = [1, 2]

my_list[0], my_list[1] = my_list[1], my_list[0]

print(my_list)

Output:
[2, 1]
```

Here is what I think this does. I set what ever is in the 0th position of my_list = to whatever is in the 1st position of my_list, which is basically saying, "Hey, trade values!". Then I do the same thing with the first position of my_list, accept I set it = what ever is in the 0th position of my list. What I think this does, and correct me if I'm wrong, is that is sets the value of the 0th position = to the value of the 1st position, and it sets the value of the 1st position = to the value of the 0th position. This in turn changes the values of the list elements, making it look as though they have traded places. Is this correct or am I overthinking this? I know this sounds like basic assignment, but I want to make sure I fully understand this concept of swapping.

Comment: you are right. Keep up the good work

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for check this. It feels good to understand something. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the actual question. What's going on during swapping is the following.

1. Python computes what is on the right side from `=` operator. That is Python gets two values `my_list[1]` and `my_list[0]` which are `2` and `1`. Then Python packs the values into tuple `(2, 1)`.
2. Python assigns the tuple `(2, 1)` to the variable on the left side from `=` operator.
3. There are 2 variables on the left side from `=` operator AND tuple `(2, 1)` has exactly 2 items. So Python unpacks the tuple then assigns `2` to the first variable (which happened to be the first element of the list `my_list`) and assigns `1` to the second variable.

So swapping values is obtained through packing and upacking hidden from user.